# BIND exception in NameNode

Tags: java, hadoop

Getting this exception:

```
    2014-09-06 23:14:04,906 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode:       Exception in namenode join
java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [master:54310] java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:719)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:534)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:2203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:897)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.<init>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:505)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:480)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:742)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.<init>(NameNodeRpcServer.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createRpcServer(NameNode.java:510)
```

This is the output of netstat:
    [hduser@xyz hadoop]$ netstat -anl|grep 54310

```
tcp        0      0 10.0.112.61:54310           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

tcp        0      0 10.0.112.61:54310           10.0.112.61:55878           ESTABLISHED

tcp        0      0 10.0.112.61:54310           198.245.16.35:43071         ESTABLISHED

tcp        0      0 10.0.112.61:55878           10.0.112.61:54310           ESTABLISHED
```

This is the /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost

::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

198.245.16.35 slave

10.0.112.61 master
```

I am using hadoop-2.2.0 on Red Hat Linux.

Somewhere else I read that Journal Node should be running when Name Node is formatted (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.mapreduce.user/7275).

Can anyone please clarify what journal node is for?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What command were you running when you got this exception?

Comment: I did sbin/start-dfs.sh on the master. The data nodes on both master and slave started. The namenode was never started on the slave. So I tried sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode on the slave. That's when the bind exception was found in the namenode log. Please see http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.mapreduce.user/7275 for the exact same problem.

Comment: try hadoop namenode on the slave and post the error message

Comment: I was still able to use Map-Reduce on the cluster. Perhaps name nodes on slaves are not as critical a required as I originally thought. Thanks for your kind comments and offer to help.